# I want to use ActiveRecord in a non Rails way. How can I get my code to put the db file in the right directory?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite, database-connection, config

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter:  sqlite3
  encoding: unicode

development:
  <<: *default  
  database: development.sqlite3   
  username: admin
  password: wsxqaz
  server:   localhost
  #  port:
```

ruby code:

```
  require "yaml"
  require "active_record"

  # shorten lines with this namespace
  include ActiveRecord::Tasks

  # trying to use db folder
  DatabaseTasks.db_dir = './db'

  db_config_file = "./config/database.yml"
  db_config = YAML.load_file(db_config_file)

  db_type = db_config['development']

  @sldbtask = SQLiteDatabaseTasks.new(db_type, root = './')
  @sldbtask.create
```

I've tried changing the root argument but that doesn't make any difference either.
What do I need to get my db file into the db directory? It creates it okay and the table stuff is pending. First things first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the database is supposed to be generated in the root directory. The db folder is used for activerecord's schema and migration files. Why is it so important that the database generates in the db directory?

**EDIT**
I just found an easier way to do this. After you require all of the files you want, then enter `set :database, {database:"./db/myDatabase.db"}`. If you already have the line `set :database` in your code, just add that to it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to try that.